# How do I sort an array of custom objects on this property?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sorting

I have an array containing custom objects with a property named `seat`. Seat can have values 1A,  1D , 1C , 1k , 2A, 2k, 2D, 2C.

Now these can be arranged in any order, and I want to sort them according to class, however the sorting only accounts for the seats numeric value and not A, C, D,or K.

I want the order to be 1A,1C,1D,1K and so on.

This is what I have implemented in the SeatDO object:

```
-(NSComparisonResult) compareBySeatNumber:(SeatDO*)other {
    NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedSame;
    NSInteger seatNumber = [self.seat integerValue];
    NSInteger otherSeatNumber = [other.seat integerValue];

    if (seatNumber > otherSeatNumber) {
        result = NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (seatNumber < otherSeatNumber) {
        result = NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return result;
}
```

How do I make it consider the letters as well..?

Comment: Is the 'seat' implemented as enum? If not, what type of object are the values of 'seat'?

Comment: @makaron seats are nsstring

Comment: Well, then Gabriele's answer should work )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you convert the seat numbers to `NSString`s

```
NSArray *sortedSeats = [seats sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]
```

should do the trick. Sorting strings will naturally follow the sort order you need.

Otherwise you could just use strings during the comparison with

```
[seats sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 stringValue] localizedStandardCompare:[obj2 stringValue]];
}];
```

I assumed that `stringValue` is available for you custom object. If not, simply replace it with anything that will return a `NSString` description of your instances.

**NOTE**

As suggested by Alladinian, you want to use `localizedStandardCompare:` as opposed to `caseInsensitiveCompare:`, in order to the get the proper lexicographic order.

Comment: Hi Gabriele (thanx for the fairplay by the way, this is what makes this community so awesome). Since your answer have been selected as correct you might want to fix a small typo: `sortedArrayUsingSelect:` should be `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`

Answer (score 3):

Use `localizedStandardCompare:` as the selector (Finder-like sorting)

```
[seats sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)]
```

While `caseInsensitiveCompare:` might seem like correct, if you add a `@"10D"` or `@"01C"` seat it would appear in front of all others...

Answer (score -2):

if you're using an NSArray you can sort it using sortedArrayUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator and it will return you another array sorted

```
NSArray *arraySorted = [myArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareBySeatNumber:)];
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't get my question.. I know how to get the sorted array, but the sorting mechanism does not account for the letters in the seat.. only the numerics.

Comment: The user wanted to know how to take in account **also the letter** when sorting, not how to sort an array

Comment: Moreover `sortedArrayUsingSelector` will send the selector the each object held by the array, which of course do not respond to `compareBySeatNumber:`. The above code would crash the app.